# How to delete message from the console?

Tags: python

I want to remove the text that appears in the console to be removed after it was typed in, I need it to be removed

```
niz = input("Insert word:")
```

so it will say in the console, "Insert word:(word that they inserted)" 
So then in the console after they have entered the word it would get deleted

Comment: Depends on what OS you're using. Please tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on **Windows** you can use:

```
import os  
user_input = input("Insert word")   
os.system('cls')
```

Alternatively if you are in **Linux / OS X**:

```
import os  
user_input = input("Insert word")
os.system('clear')
```

Comment: I keep getting a error code "sh: 1: cls: not found"

Comment: I'm so sorry I am using a site called repl.it and I didn't notice that it was running on linux.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you don't have full control over the end-user's terminal--your program simply sends text to standard output, and once it has been printed, it's under the control of the user's operating system or terminal emulator, so you can't take it back. There are three possible approaches though which might correspond to what you're trying to do.

The first option would be to simply clear the screen. This doesn't technically "delete" what they entered, because they could still scroll up and see the text, but at least it will no longer be immediately visible on the screen.

```
import os
os.system('cls')
os.system('clear')
```

The second option would be to treat this as a password field. This would suppress the text from ever being echoed at all, so when the person starts typing, nothing appears on screen, but you still receive input.

```
import getpass
mystring = getpass.getpass()
```

You can use `getpass.getpass(prompt="Input: ")` to change the default prompt (`Password:`).

Finally, if neither of those two methods work for you, I would recommend using the `curses` module. This is a more complicated process, but it will achieve exactly what you want to do. The code below simply displays a string, then when the user presses enter will erase the string, and then when you press enter again it ends the program. Please check the [curses Python manual page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) for more details on how to use `curses`.

```
import curses

# initialize a curses window
stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
stdscr.keypad(True)

win = curses.newwin(5, 40, 0, 0) # create window at top-left of terminal with height 5 and width 40
win.refresh()
mystring = "hello, world"
win.addstr(mystring) # print a string to the window
win.refresh()
win.getkey() # wait for user input
curpos = curses.getsyx() # get current cursor position
win.move(curpos[0], curpos[1]-len(mystring)) # move the cursor to the beginning of the string
win.refresh()
win.clrtoeol() # erase text from cursor to end of line
win.refresh()
win.getkey() # wait for user input

# close the curses window and return terminal to normal functionality
stdscr.keypad(False)
curses.echo()
curses.endwin()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via terminal code.
For windows you do

```
clear = lambda:os.system('cls')
```

for Linux you do

```
clear = lambda:os.system('clear')
```

And you just have to call clear()

Answer (score 0):

You can use an echo-free input function such as `getpass` to remove the need to delete the user input:

```
import getpass

niz = getpass.getpass(prompt="Insert word:")

print(f'You entered: {niz}')
```

Output:

```
Insert word:
You entered: secret
```